# Jscript mouse hover over menu always displaying behind other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cakephp-3.0

I need some help with my navigation bar item, i have a shopping cart that is supposed to expand on mouse over. Which works, but the expansion is appearing behind other menu items and i cant figure out why. I have tried putting the z-index to ridiculous values and made the position absolute. Still no success.

Here is the Nav html:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">

 <div class="container" style="background-color: #2a3968; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse  nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:-10px;">
       <li style = "color:white;">
            <?php
                if($this->request->session()->read('Auth')) {
               // user is logged in, show "account" link
                echo $this->Html->link(__('Account'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'Index']);
                }
            ?>
        </li>
        <span style="color:white; margin-top:-15px;">
        <li style = "color:white; margin-right:15px;">
            <?php
                if($this->request->session()->read('Auth')) {
                // user is logged in, show logout..user menu etc
                echo $this->Html->link(__('Logout'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']);
                } else {
                // the user is not logged in
                echo '<span style="color:white">'.$this->Html->link(__('Login/Register'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']).'</span>';
                }
            ?>
        </li> 
        </span>     
    </ul>
</div>

    <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:-25px; margin-bottom:-15px;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>                   
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="http://localhost/team12/pages/home">
        <img src="http://ie.infotech.monash.edu/Team12/Build4/GIT/webroot/img/silverdeals.png" class= "logo" style=" padding-bottom:10px; height:70px; float:left;">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="vertical-align:center; color:white; padding-top:10px; padding-right:-15px;">
    <ul>



            <li style="display: inline-block; float:right;"> 
            <?php

              echo $this->element('quick_cart');
            ?>
            </li>
            <li style="display: inline-block; float:right;"> | </li>
            <li style="display: inline-block; float:right; "> Secure Shipping anytime </li>
            <li style="display: inline-block; float:right; "> | </li>
            <li style="display: inline-block; float:right; "> <?php echo $this->element('search');?> </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Home'), ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Products'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'Index']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Arrivals'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'newarrivals']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Rings'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'rings']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Bracelets'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'bracelets']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Earrings'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'earrings']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Necklaces'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'necklaces']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Sales'), ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'sales']) ?></li>

        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Contact Us'), ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'About']) ?></li>



        </ul>   
    </div>

</nav>
```

Here is the shopping cart code:

```
<style>
    .hide{display:none}
    .quickcart {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99999;
      width: 300px;
      border: 10px solid #bebebe;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 8px 10px 10px;
      color: #000000;
      right:1%;
    }
    #show-quick-cart {
      cursor:auto;
      float:none;
      color: #000000;
      z-index:2000;
      font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:120%;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      box-sizing:inherit;
    }
    .nav{
      z-index: 100;
    }
</style>

<div id="pardiv" style=" color:white;">
 <?php
            $counter = $this->request->session()->read('Cart.count');
            echo $this->Html->link('<span style="color:white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><span style="color:white; "></span><span class="badge" id="cart-counter"><?php echo $counter ;?></span>', array('controller'=>'Pages','action'=>'display','shoppingCart'), array('escape'=>false, 'id'=>'show-quick-cart'));
            ?>
<div id="show-quick-cart-zone">
    <div id="quickcart" class="quickcart hide">
        <div class="quickcarttitle"><span><b>Your cart</b></span></div>
        <div class="quickcart-products">
            <?php if ($this->request->session()->check('Cart.items')){
            ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>


                                <th> </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <?php
                        $products = $this->request->session()->read('Cart.items');
                        $cartTotal = 0;
                        foreach ($products as $product):
                        ?>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="<?= h($product['PicURL']) ?>" alt="BlueMountain"></td>


                                    <td><?php echo $product['Quantity'];?></td>
                                    <?php if(isset($product['SalePrice'])){
                                        $cartTotal += $product['SalePrice']*$product['Quantity'];
                                         ?>
                                         <td><?php echo $product['SalePrice']*$product['Quantity'];?></td>
                                         <?php
                                         }

                                        else {
                                        $cartTotal += $product['UnitPrice']*$product['Quantity'];
                                         ?>
                                         <td><?php echo $product['UnitPrice']*$product['Quantity']; ?></td>
                                         <?php
                                         }
                                         ?>
                                    <td><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('x'), ['controller'=>'products', 'action' => 'removeFromCart', $product['ProductID']], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to remove {0} from the cart?', $product['ProductName'])]) ?></td>
                                </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><b>Total:</b></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $cartTotal; ?> </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
            </div>

            <?php
            } else {
            ?>
                <p><b> is empty!</b></p>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    var flag=0;
    $('#show-quick-cart').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#quickcart').slideDown(500);
        return false;
    });
    $('#pardiv').mouseleave(function () {

        $('#quickcart').slideUp(500);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you all very much.

Comment: I tried, unsuccessfully, to create [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smLam9ea/) ; if you could update it such that it replicates your problem, that might help